# `–` showing up as `--` in font defined with \newfontfamily in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm using XeLaTeX to compile a document, and I'm quite confused. I noticed that the character `–` (the en dash) shows up as a normal `–` in the main document, but as `--` (two hyphens) when written with a font family I defined, although they are using the same font. Here's a MWE to show what I mean:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\setmainfont[SizeFeatures={Size=12]{CMU Sans Serif}
\newfontfamily\somefontfamily[SizeFeatures={Size=12}]{CMU Sans Serif}

\begin{document}

{\somefontfamily The -- looks strange}

But here -- it looks just fine.

\end{document}
```

Why is there a difference, even though I'm using the same font?

Comment: Add the option `Ligatures=TeX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fontspec` package reads `fontspec.cfg` (in a standard directory, so it can be locally overridden), which contains

```
\defaultfontfeatures
 [\rmfamily,\sffamily]
 {Ligatures=TeX}

\defaultfontfeatures
 [\ttfamily]
 {WordSpace={1,0,0},
  HyphenChar=None,
  PunctuationSpace=WordSpace}
```

This means that `Ligatures=TeX` is only applied to `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`; other features are applied for `\setmonofont`.

Such default features might not be desired for other font families, thus you have to add `Ligatures=TeX` yourself to other declared families. So

```
\newfontfamily\somefontfamily[Ligatures=TeX,SizeFeatures={Size=12}]{CMU Sans Serif}
```

or (new syntax)

```
\newfontfamily\somefontfamily{CMU Sans Serif}[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  SizeFeatures={Size=12}
]
```